# Java reading XML from URL in UTF-8?

Tags: java, xml, utf-8

I'm trying to parse XML data from a URL but I cannot seem to get it to parse it as UTF-8 as the `¥` character gets messed up when reading it from the response:

```
URL url = new URL("https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=¥");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
final InputStream in = url.openStream();
final InputSource source = new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
source.setEncoding("UTF-8");
Document doc = db.parse(source);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if(node==null || listItems.size() > 10){
        break;
    }
    String suggestion = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getTextContent();
    // ...suggestions include � instead of ¥
}
```

`source.setEncoding()` was an accepted answer in another thread, but didn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that the encoding of input file is different than UTF-8.

These works for me:

Read the document with ISO-8859-1 encoding

```
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1")));
```

The final method is like:

```
URL url = new URL("https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&hl=en&q=¥");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "ISO-8859-1")));
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("suggestion");

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Node node = nodeList.item(i);
    if(node==null){
        break;
    }
    String suggestion = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("data").getTextContent();
    System.out.println(suggestion);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this server is violating the HTTP and XML specs. When I send the request, the server clearly sends back `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8` so per the HTTP standards UTF-8 MUST be used for parsing the XML. The XML is missing an `encoding` attribute in its prolog, so UTF-8 would be the default charset to use anyway. But the actual content of the XML is indeed encoded in ISO-8859-1, not UTF-8, which contradicts what the server is claiming.